# Calculating Riemann-Stieltjes-Integral

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

I'm supposed to calculate the Riemann–Stieltjes integral $\int_{[0,4]} f(s)\,dZ(s)$ for $i\in(0,1)$, $f(s) = (1+i)^{\lfloor s \rfloor}$ and $Z(s) = \begin{cases} s^2, & 0 \le s \lt 1\\ 2, & 1 \le s \lt 2\\
s, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

I have essentially no experience with this so here is my attempt:

\begin{align}
& \int_{[0,4]} f(s)\,dZ(s) \\[8pt]
= {} &  \int_{[0,1)} f(s)\,dZ(s) + \int_{[1,2)} f(s)\,dZ(s) \\[4pt]
& {} + \int_{[2,3)} f(s)\,dZ(s) + \int_{[3,4]} f(s)\,dZ(s) \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_{[0,1)} 1 \cdot 2s \, ds + \int_{[1,2)} (i+1) \cdot 0 \, ds \\[4pt]
& {} +\int_{[2,3)} (i+1)^2 \, ds + \int_{[3,4]}(i+1)^3\,ds \\[8pt]
= {} & 1 +0+(i+1)^2 + (i+1)^3
\end{align}

Is that right?

EDIT:

My new attempt is as follows:

Let $X(s) := \begin{cases} s^2, & 0 \le s \lt 1\\ 1, & 1 \le s \lt 2\\
s-1, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Then $X$ is continous and we have \begin{align}
& \int_{[0,4]} f(s)\,dX(s) \\[8pt]
= {} &  \int_{[0,1)} f(s)\,dX(s) + \int_{[1,2)} f(s)\,dX(s) \\[4pt]
& {} + \int_{[2,3)} f(s)\,dX(s) + \int_{[3,4]} f(s)\,dX(s) \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_{[0,1)} 1 \cdot 2s \, ds + \int_{[1,2)} (i+1) \cdot 0 \, ds \\[4pt]
& {} +\int_{[2,3)} (i+1)^2 \, ds + \int_{[3,4]}(i+1)^3\,ds \\[8pt]
= {} & 1 +0+(i+1)^2 + (i+1)^3
\end{align}

Now let $Y(s) := \begin{cases} 0, & 0 \le s \lt 1\\ 1, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Then we have $Z(s) = X(s) + Y(s)$ and \begin{align}
& \int_{[0,4]} f(s)\,dY(s) = \int_{[0,4]} f(s)\,\delta_1(ds) = 1+i \end{align}

(I'm pretty sure up until here this should be right, the part I am really unsure about comes now:)

$\therefore$ \begin{align}
& \int_{[0,4]} f(s)\,dZ(s) = \int_{[0,4]} f(s)\,d(X(s)+Y(s))
= \int_{[0,4]} f(s)\,dX(s) + \int_{[0,4]} f(s)\,dY(s) \\[8 pt]
= {} & 1 +(i+1)^2 + (i+1)^3 + 1+i
\end{align}

Is this now correct? Can I split up the integrator like that?

Comment: You would be OK if the integrator $Z$ were continuous, so there were no jumps.  But your $Z$ has a jump of size $1$ at $s=1$.  And the integrand $f(s)$ is also discontiuous at $s=1$.  Your calculation must take these into account.  (It turns out you can ignore discontinuities in $f$ as long as there is no jump in $Z$ there.)

Comment: As pointed out, the noncontinuity of $Z$ across the boundaries is problematic. However, by abstract nonsense (bounded variation), the integral must converge, so any filtration of partitions will work. Specifically pick partitions that converge around $1$ and $2$ and use continuity of $f$ to evaluate the left-right limits.